# What's the value of f1 score when true positives are zero?

Tags: machine-learning, confusion-matrix, f-statistic

f1 score is defined as F1 = 2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)
However if true positives are zero, this gives 0/0. How to deal with this scenario?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated. I hope that link helps. If not, please edit your question and we'll do our best to help!